# Why do my threads not run in parallel using Java ExecutorService?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, parallel-processing, executorservice

```
public class Test {
    private ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(50);

    public void startTenThreads() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            executor.execute(new FooWorker(i));
        }
    }

    private final class FooWorker implements Runnable {
        private int threadNum;

        public FooWorker(int threadNum) {
            this.threadNum = threadNum;
        }

        public void run() {
            System.out.println("Thread " + threadNum + " starting");
            Thread.sleep(60000);
            System.out.println("Thread " + threadNum + " finished");
        }
    }
}
```

I want these threads to run in parallel, however the output shows it is not running in parallel, but rather sequentially:

```
Thread 1 starting
Thread 1 finished
Thread 2 starting
Thread 2 finished
Thread 3 starting
Thread 3 finished
Thread 4 starting
Thread 4 finished
Thread 5 starting
Thread 5 finished
...
```

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT: Found the problem, somebody had set the thread pool size to 1. This snippet code works fine**

Comment: Because you tasks take such a sort time to complete that they execute before the next loop iteration. You need to provide threads with more work - a random sleep perhaps. Also look at [`invokeAll`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#invokeAll(java.util.Collection)).

Comment: You need to print a ton more lines.  You are dealing with race conditions and the threads are finishing too fast.

Comment: I put Thread.sleep(60000) and it still prints in the same order

Comment: as Boris the Spider said try ,  `public void run() {
            System.out.println("Thread " + threadNum + " starting");
           try {
   Thread.sleep(100);
  } catch (InterruptedException e) {
   
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
            System.out.println("Thread " + threadNum + " finished");
        }` It worked for me

Comment: It doesn't compile if you just add sleep the way you did.  Can you give us the actual code?

Comment: hmm yes thanks for the comments, you guys are right this code snippet works just fine. there is something wrong within my actual code that is causing it to not run in parallel...

Comment: @Popcorn sounds like you are `synchronized` somewhere.

Comment: okay never mind this was a really dumb bug, somebody set the thread pool size to 1 :[

Comment: i was trying to use newSingleThreadExecutor() to run threads in parallel. pretty foolish of me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code as written doesn't compile. I'm guessing you have something else going on in code that you did not cut/paste here. Here is your code written to compile. I tested it and it works for me. What is the difference between your actual code and the code below? (Please excuse the typo in "TheadTest".)

```
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

public class TheadTest {

    private ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(50);

    public void startTenThreads() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            executor.execute(new FooWorker(i));
        }
    }

    private final class FooWorker implements Runnable {
        private int threadNum;

        public FooWorker(int threadNum) {
            this.threadNum = threadNum;
        }

        public void run() {
            try {
                System.out.println("Thread " + threadNum + " starting");
                Thread.sleep(60000);
                System.out.println("Thread " + threadNum + " finished");
            }
            catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TheadTest tt = new TheadTest();
        tt.startTenThreads();
    }

}
```

Comment: There's a lot of differences so I don't think I can paste all of it. I'm still trying to figure this out, but the gist is I'm sending http requests with apache http client and I want them to all run in parallel. I think it may have to do with using HttpClient instead of AsyncHttpClient. Still looking into it